# Incompatible types; found: interface java.util.List<java.lang.Object>, required: interface java.util.List<test.entity.Emp>

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following class structure

```
public class Emp implements java.io.Serializable {

....

}

public interface EmployeeDAO  {

 public List<Emp> findAllEmployees();

}

public class EmployeeDAOImpl  implements EmployeeDAO {

    public List<Emp> findAllEmployees() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Emp.class));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
...

}
```

---

Issue I am having is

```
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

The above line gives me the following error, what could be the reason for this?

```
incompatible types; found: interface java.util.List<java.lang.Object>, 
required: interface java.util.List<test.entity.Emp>
```

The same code works in other higher version of Java.
My current JDK is 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell the `CriteraQuery` which type it will return.

```
public List<Emp> findAllEmployees() {
    CriteriaQuery<Emp> cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Emp.class);
    cq.select(cq.from(Emp.class));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```